# Is there way to add to shopify admin menu new menu item?

Tags: menu, shopify

I found how to add new menu item for shop. But it's not that what I was looking for. Is there some way to add in shopify admin new item for example after "Orders" or to orders sub-menu, Or just change content on "Orders" page in admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to add items in Left Menu. However, you can add links on Top menu using App Links (Refer to Settings of the app in your Partner Account)